# Python Regex: Remove the parts of the string that does not match regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove parts of the string that does not match the format that I want. Example:

```
import re 

string = 'remove2017abcdremove'     
pattern = re.compile("((20[0-9]{2})([a-zA-Z]{4}))")
result = pattern.search(string)

if result:
    print('1')
else:
    print('0')
```

It returns "1" so I can find the matching format inside the string however I also want to remove the parts that says "remove" on it.

I want it to return:

```
desired_output = '2017abcd'
```

Comment: So have you looked at what `result` contains, or read the appropriate docs?

Comment: You could print `print(result.group())` and simplify the pattern by removing the capturing groups `20[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{4}`

Comment: `desired_output = pattern.findall(string)[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify group from search result, which is done through calling a `group()`:

```
import re 

string = 'remove2017abcdremove'     
pattern = re.compile("(20[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{4})")
string = pattern.search(string).group()

# 2017abcd
```